# Kup Backup plan failed Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, backup, rsync

I am trying to back up my `home` folder to my secondary HD. I am getting this error message:

```
Kup is starting rsync backup job at Monday, July 4, 2022 10:56:31 PM MST
rsync "-avX" "--delete-excluded" "--delete-before" "--info=progress2" "--exclude" "/krillavilla/.cache" "--exclude" "/krillavilla/.local/share/Trash" "--exclude" "/krillavilla/.local/share/baloo" "--exclude-from" "/home/krillavilla/" "/home/krillavilla" "/media/krillavilla/1TB/Kashad"
rsync: [generator] recv_generator: mkdir "/media/krillavilla/1TB/Kashad/krillavilla/.java/.userPrefs/_!(:!bw"m!(@!dw"h!()!~@!u!'%!dw"z!#4!d!"v!'8!b!"r!'k!d!"z!#4!ag"l!(@!}g"y!'%!a@"u!(:!.g"z!'`!d!"0!'k!bg"n!(:!.g"%!'`!~g"h!(`!b!"0!%%!dw"z!&:!~@"0!(@!a@"u!'c!cw==" failed: Invalid argument (22)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
rsync: [generator] recv_generator: mkdir "/media/krillavilla/1TB/Kashad/krillavilla/.java/.userPrefs/jetbrains/_!(!!cg"p!(}!}@"j!(k!|w"w!'8!b!"p!':!e@==" failed: Invalid argument (22)
*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***
rsync: [generator] symlink "/media/krillavilla/1TB/Kashad/krillavilla/snap/masscode/common/.cache/gio-modules/*.so" -> "/snap/masscode/x1/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/*.so" failed: Invalid argument (22)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1333) [sender=3.2.3]

Exit code: 23
Kup did not successfully complete the rsync backup job.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my issue above.

The article below:

[Rsync fails to backup some files, giving error 22](https://serverfault.com/questions/213647/rsync-fails-to-backup-some-files-giving-error-22)

I had to format my secondary HD using `KDE Partition Manager` application.

I used `ext3` as my format from Linux FileSystems.

Here are commands for anyone having issues in  the near future:

```
Create a new partition (931.51 GiB, ext3) on ‘/dev/sda’

Job: Create new partition on device ‘/dev/sda’:

Command: sfdisk --force --append /dev/sda

Command: sfdisk --list --output Device,UUID /dev/sda

Job: Create file system ‘ext3’ on partition ‘/dev/sda1’:

Command: mkfs.ext3 -qF /dev/sda1

Command: sfdisk --part-type /dev/sda 1 0FD63XFF-8913-4779-2C79-3A26B8477EC8

Job: Set the file system label on partition ‘/dev/sda1’ to "Label your Partition":

Command: e2label /dev/sda1 1 TB Secondary

Job: Check file system on partition ‘/dev/sda1’:

Command: e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda1

Job: Change the permissions of: ‘/dev/sda1’ to:

Command: mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/partitionmanager-ejSYpx

Command: chmod 777 /tmp/partitionmanager-ejSYpx --recursive

Command: umount /dev/sda1
```